# methods to find causality between 1000 time series

Tags: time-series, clustering, granger-causality

I have an eco-system of 100 applications which each are monitored by let's say 100 metrics publishing every 5 minutes. So my dataset has 10,000 time series. I want to build/learn the dependency graph of my eco-system.

Basically, I want to know, in an unsupervised way, which time series is affecting others. What I did so far is, running some clustering on each application to reduce the number of metrics for each application to 10. And now I'm thinking to apply some causality tests like Granger causality for 1000 time series. But the number of possible combinations to test is very high and I more likely will get high false positives. So what can I do to achieve this goal better?